# Dialog QtQuick 1.1 rounded corners

Tags: dialog, qml, rounded-corners

I'm building my own QML Dialog. Therefore I want to make a header, content and footer item. The Dialog should have rounded corners (Rectangle.radius) but the Header/Footer should be a normal Rectangle.

Heres my code:

```
    Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Rectangle {
        id: dialog
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 300
        radius: 20
        border.color: "gainsboro"

        Rectangle {
            id: header
            width: dialog.width
            height: 50
            border.color: "red"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "HEADER"
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: footer
            anchors.bottom: dialog.bottom
            width: dialog.width
            height: 50
            border.color: "green"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "FOOTER"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the Dialog does not have rounded corners, because the header and footer are overlapping the dialog Rectangle. I would like to know how to avoid that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider leaving some top and bottom margin ?

Comment: I already tried margins, but there's always the problem with overlapping or gap areas of the rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, `headerContent` and `fooderContent` would contain all of the header and footer contents.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    color: "black"
    width: 450
    height: 600

    Item {
        id: dialog
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 300

        Rectangle {
            id: header
            width: dialog.width
            height: 50 * 2
            anchors.top: parent.top
            radius: 20
            border.color: "red"

            Item {
                id: headerContent
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height / 2
                anchors.top: parent.top

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "HEADER"
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: footer
            width: dialog.width
            height: 50 * 2
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            radius: 20
            border.color: "green"

            Item {
                id: footerContent
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height / 2
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "FOOTER"
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            anchors.top: header.verticalCenter
            anchors.bottom: footer.verticalCenter
            border.color: "gainsboro"
        }
    }
}
```

If this is still not what you're looking for, you may want to use [Canvas](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a header and footer children of `dialog`, make them siblings and set header and footer `z` property lower than the main rect

Comment: If I do that, I cannot access (click) the header and footer items, cause of the overlapping dialog-rectangle.

Comment: change their anchors -> header `anchors.bottom:dialog.top` and footer `anchors.top:dialog.bottom`

Comment: When I do that, the corners of my dialog aren't round.

Comment: Is there no way to round just two corners of a rectangle? - I figured out, that I can use two [BorderImages](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-borderimage.html#details) for the header and footer-item. The header-image with rounded corners on top and a mirrored version for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this simple solution as I was looking for a way to add round corner to my Dialog in Qt 6:

```
// RoundDialog

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Dialog {
    background: Rectangle {
        property int _offset: 4
        x: -_offset
        y: -_offset
        width: parent.width + _offset * 2
        height: parent.height + _offset * 2
        radius: _offset * 3
    }
}
```